# Creating a recursive sequence in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, integer, sequence

I was wondering how could you write a recursive method that accepts an integer parameter (n) and writes the following sequence: n, n-1, n-2,n-3,..., 0, ... -(n-3), -(n-2), -(n-1), -n. For example: 5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5

What would be the base case for this example?
How will the method know when to end?

So far I have:

```js
public static void createSequence(int n) {
 if (n== 0)
     return;
 else{
     System.out.println(n);
     createSequence(n-1);
      }
  }
```

This only creates a sequence of positive integers, how can I fix this code?

Comment: Hint: you need to write something after the call to `createSequence(n - 1)`

Comment: Is the input integer guaranteed to be non-negative?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to write -n after the recursive call:

```
public static void createSequence(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
        return;
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println(n);
        createSequence(n-1);
        System.out.println(-n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but it's not tail recursive

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing in the JVM to optimize tail-recursion, so that doesn't really matter. I wouldn't implement this algorithm recursively anyway, other than to learn what you can do with recursion.

Comment: @Xephi: There's nothing in the question asking for tail-recursion.

Comment: @greybeard sure ! That was just to give an extra information, not a real critic, i've still upvote it :)

Comment: You can remove the `else` there. Make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm late to the party, but here's mine:

```
public static void createSequence(int n){
    System.out.println(n);
    if(n==0) return;
    createSequence(n-Integer.signum(n));
    System.out.println(-n);
}
```

Works with positive and negative input.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, I think, would be to write an auxiliary recursive method:

```
public static void createSequence(int n) {
    writeSequence(n, -n);
}
private static void writeSequence(int current, int limit) {
    if (current >= limit) {
        System.out.println(current);
        writeSequence(current - 1, limit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you usually use a helper method for the recursive call:

```
public static void createSequence(int n) {
    createSequenceHelper(n, -n); // be sure that 'n' is positive here
}

private static void createSequenceHelper(int n, int limit) {
    if (n >= limit) {
        System.out.println(n);
        createSequenceHelper(n - 1, limit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass original number as a second parameter to do a check :

```
public static void createSequence(int n, int limit) {
    if (n < limit)
        return;
    else{
        System.out.println(n);
        createSequence(n-1, limit);
    }
}
```

Also by using : `createSequence(5, -5);`, it will print:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !

```
public static void createSequence(int n) {
    if (n== 0){
        System.out.println(0);
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println(n);
        createSequence(n-1);
        System.out.println(n*-1);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to solve your issue is the below code. Here start should be initialized to n before calling this recursive function. (start=n;)

```
public static void createSequence(int n, int start) {
if (start + n == 0)
    return;
else{
    System.out.println(n);
    createSequence(n-1, start);
  } 
}
```